# Snowflake SQL count distinct with window function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset with weekly customer and store information,

**question- I have to calculate features such as total unique customers in last 1,2,3,4,5,6..so on weeks as of current week.**

I am getting **error** while using count distinct of customers column over window function -

I tried concat function to create array which also didn't work- thanks for help!

```
SELECT STORE,WEEK,

count(distinct Customers) over (partition by STORE order by WEEK rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as last_1_week_customers,
count(distinct Customers) over (partition by STORE order by WEEK rows between 2 preceding and 2 preceding) as last_2_week_customers
    from TEST_TABLE
    group by STORE,WEEK
```

**error-    SQL compilation error: distinct cannot be used with a window frame or an order.**

how can I fix this error?

**Input**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (STORE STRING,WEEK STRING,Customers STRING);


INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES

('A','1','AA'),
('A','1','DD'),
('A','2','AA'),
('A','2','BB'),
('A','2','CC'),
('A','3','AA');
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: So where is the query and what errors does it produce? And what's the question?

Comment: updated with query and error

Comment: Thanks! I've posted an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I think you don't really need window functions here at all...

First of all, we can start off with a simple grouping:

```
select
    store,
    week,
    count(distinct customers) as cnt
from
    test_table
where
    week >= [this week's number minus 5]
group by
   store, week
```

This will result in a simple table:

| store | week | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 1 |

At this point I'd ask you to consider if maybe this is already enough. It could be that you can already use the data in this format for whatever purpose you need. But if not, then we can further modify this to get a "pivoted" output.

In this query, replace `${w}` with this week's number:

```
select
    store,
    count(distinct case when week=${w} then customers else null end) as cnt_now,
    count(distinct case when week=${w-1} then customers else null end) as cnt_minus_1,
    count(distinct case when week=${w-2} then customers else null end) as cnt_minus_2,
    count(distinct case when week=${w-3} then customers else null end) as cnt_minus_3,
    count(distinct case when week=${w-4} then customers else null end) as cnt_minus_4,
    count(distinct case when week=${w-5} then customers else null end) as cnt_minus_5
from
    test_table
where
    week >= {$w-5}
group by
   store
```

Remember - `COUNT()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` only count **NON-NULL** values.

| store | cnt_now | cnt_minus_1 | cnt_minus_2 | cnt_minus_3 | cnt_minus_4 | cnt_minus_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| B | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |

Comment: Thanks for your response, in this case when I am calculating last 2 weeks, I have to take count distinct of all customers in last 1 and 2 combined , similarly last 6 week will include last 1,2,3,4,5,6 count distinct- which is why I was trying to use count distinct over window function

Comment: @Jack - Sure! This is flexible. Just modify the condition inside the `case` statements.

Comment: @Jack - Mind you, you HAVE to know what columns will be returned. You cannot have a query which will have an unknown number of columns returned. MySQL does not support that. You need to describe each column. So if you want the number of columns to change depending on what data you have - sorry, that's not possible.